# TFS - Project File was not found

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a large solution in TFS that consists of 28 projects. The build definition currently does a full build each time, and works correctly. I changed "Clean Workspaces" to "None" in an attempt to enable incremental builds, but when I queue a new build after changing the definition it fails immediately with the following message:

```
Exception Message: The project file 'E:\Builds\43\154\Sources\MyProject\Project.smproj' was not found. (type FileNotFoundException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

The strange thing is, it works again if I switch "Clean Workspaces" back to "All". This error only crops up when it's set to "None".

What should I be looking for that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is correct. To enable incremental builds, you just need to edit the build definition in Visual Studio and set the Clean Workspace property to “None”.

When we set the “Clean Workspace = None” in Build Definition, MSBuild will skip to build the “unchanged” project automatically. However, Its something that will save a lot of time during the build process, but can potentially cause a lot of headache if not configured properly. There must be a one-to-one mapping between inputs and outputs. You can use transforms to enable targets to identify this direct mapping. More info from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264087(v=vs.140).aspx

Considering the scenario you mentioned I would not advise incremental builds. By not deleting the workspace you benefit by the reduced time of build completion however you may run into conflicts.